# Typo3, Multiple News Details & Lists on one page

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want to use the News system extension from Georg Ringer like this:

Multiple News Details & Lists All on one page

the Detail view on top of the "cards" of the List view should show the Detail of the item clicked on

The behavior seems like to allow multiple list but only 1 detail view

---

### Detail View of "Services"

### List View of "Services"

### ------ other stuff

### Detail View of "Projects"

### List View of "Projects"

### ------ other stuff

### Detail View of "Sectors"

### List View of "Sectors"

Has anyone experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the list view to handle the first news entry with much more information. In Fluid you have access to all needed fields for displaying it like in detail view.

Then, you only need three list views on the page with your special template. No need for a detail view.

Comment: Hi Thomas - Sounds like a good idea - only issue might be that I will have to show a detail by default and not have a state where there is no detail shown. It will also be difficult to make a clicked item the first one on a reload without some JavaScript to process after a load. 

I was thinking of just load all the data and (if the items stay below 20 should not be an issue) and use JavaScript to decide which to sow as detail - but it will break SEO

Comment: Ah, you want to display dynamically in detail view what was selected in list view? Then you need to use an AJAX to load the news article. This shouldn't be a problem, should it? Here I have a small example for getting data via AJAX: https://gist.github.com/spoonerWeb/f341b393441dc45c08e1a2fdd4346059

Comment: Hi Thomas - thx - 
I decided against ajax since the Typo3 cache system write separate cached "pages" for separate detail views with unique URLs allowing it to be indexed by SEO-spiders/crawlers. Ajax will circumvent that.
I wanted to display 3 different lists on a single page to allow maximum access to them from the relevant page: 
Our Projects, Our Tasks, Our Industry Sectors
The detail view should be loaded on the page on top of the relevant list and not at the top of the page:
http://sja.com.au/images/demoNewsMultipleLists.png

Comment: You can make a "default" detail view as well and give it to the spiders. For this special view, you load it via AJAX. Don't see there any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's possible what you desire but you've to adjust the detail-view in the plugins statically to a special detail or you always will only be able to display one detail at a moment, no matter which category because news is like probably all TYPO3-extensions not programmed with the ability to transfer parameters for several plugins on a page at once.
Many years ago when extensions still have been programmed fundamentally different I had some similar desires related to other extensions and programmed something which transferred the parameters always related to each plugin on a page, so it was possible to regulate several plugins of the same type on a page separated. Today it will be harder probably to implement something like that.

What you can do is to look in the manual about the AJAX-posibilities of news. There might be still an option to fetch the detail for each of the categories separated, perhaps even on page-load already, but it will be a nifty setup which takes probably some time.

Comment: Thanks David. I have put different categories of news - e.g. PROJECTS and SERVICES in different folders. I also have them on separate category trees. I then told the detail to only show news from a specific category - but it does not work - If one of the detail views picks up the detail it shows it in the other as well.

I guess will have to duplicate the page 3 times and make the detail page look exactly like the parent page and tell different lists to  go to different pages for details

Comment: Actually I don't see how your new approach would solve the issue, but give it a try if you think it could work. IMO the Ajax-approach is really the only one which could work, but not out-of-the-box and you had to be quite creative to get it running.

Comment: Thx David - The ajax method is something I did a couple of years back but had issues with SEO.

Comment: Is not possible with news, especially as the underlying framework extbase never supports the required parameters.